# How to find ansi value of a char in java?

Tags: java

I need to get the ANSI value of a char in java

Ive tried casting my char to an int type but it returns a value that is not 
its ANSI value.

is there any way to do this?

one letter in hebrew which is "ל" has the ansi value of 236 but when i cast it to int i get 1500

Comment: What inputs have you used, and what outputs do you get, and how is this different to what you expect

Comment: What is an "ANSI value" ? ANSI is the "American National Standards Institute". They have thousands of different standards.

Comment: @hat: I'd be wary of any site claiming to be an "ASCII converter" that then accepts non-ASCII characters like the one the OP is trying to cast... (There's no such thing as "ASCII 1500"...)

Comment: @hat run this in vbscript and youll see that it isnt

Comment: @hat msgbox(Asc("ל"))

Comment: @ItayS: Its *Unicode code point* is 1500. But "ANSI" isn't a single standard, as per Erwin's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call "ANSI" is actually the [Windows codepage 1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) character set (`Windows-1255`). It's the Hebrew codepage from Microsoft.

You can get your character value in that encoding using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String s = "ל";
    byte[] b = s.getBytes("Windows-1255");
    System.out.println(b[0] & 0xff);
}
```

This prints:

```
236
```

(Note: this also works on other operating systems than Windows, such as MacOS)

Answer (score -2):

```
char[] chars = {'&','a'};
for(int i =0; i<chars.length; i++)
System.out.println(Character.codePointAt(chars,i));
```

I think the value that you are referring to is the codepoint of the character. There are many ways to do this which you can find on the documentation page of java about Characters.